# How to check if a random generated number is repeated from a button click? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

This is my code so far. It's basically a randomizer based on images. I got the random pictures to change, but I realized that the images repeat if the generated number is repeated again from the button clicked. Is there a way I can display that message? Like the number has been repeated again. Sorry, I'm still a javascript newbie.

```
btnRandom.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const numRandom = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 9);
    console.log(numRandom);

    characterEl.src = `img/genshin_characters/card-${numRandom}.webp`;

    if (numRandom) {
        console.log('you got the same character again!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't generate a new random number each time. Make an array of all the numbers, shuffle it, then select the next element from the array each time.

Comment: strictly speaking, you could keep an array of used numbers and add to it each time and check it using array.includes() - but I like Barmar's suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you don't want to random same number twice in a row. So use a variable to *remember* the last one.

```js
var last
btnRandom.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var numRandom
  while ((numRandom = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 9)) === last) {
    console.log("will randomize again");
  }
  console.log(numRandom)
  // characterEl.src = `img/genshin_characters/card-${numRandom}.webp`;
  last = numRandom
});
```

```html
<button id="btnRandom">btnRandom</button>
```

Comment: `var` in 2022? :)

Comment: it worked for so many years I'd hate to change it

Comment: Up vote because I think this works better than the suggested shuffled array.  A shuffled array would cause the user to always get one of each for each cycle. Whereas with this answer the user could get the same card again after a couple of clicks. And yeah, I love the retro var too :D

Comment: Thanks, guys! I'll still consider the shuffled array suggestion to see how it works. But for now, it works thank you IT goldman.